# How to change the coordinates of an object in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently,I was learning unity 3d, I want to make an object move a distance by C#,I don't know if I'm right,that's what I write:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class sceneTransform : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed=0.1f;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(transform.position.z<7){
            transform.position += new Vector3 (0.2,0,0)*speed*Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how your code fails to work? Have you tried increasing `speed` significantly, since at the moment your object is going to move really, really slow?

Comment: when debugging,it have errors: **Assets/Scripts/sceneTransform.cs(15,68): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for "UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)" has some invalid arguments**,and **Assets/Scripts/sceneTransform.cs(15,68): error CS1503: Argument "#1 " cannot convert  "double" expression to type "float"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the error:

**Assets/Scripts/sceneTransform.cs(15,68): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for "UnityEngine.Vector3.Vector3(float, float, float)" has some invalid arguments,and Assets/Scripts/sceneTransform.cs(15,68): error CS1503: Argument "#1 " cannot convert "double" expression to type "float"**

When working with floats in Unity3D, you need to put an "f" after them, like:

```
Vector3(0.2f,0f,0f);
```

Answer (score 3):

The arguments for Vector3 need to be in float.

```
transform.position += new Vector3 (0.2f,0,0) * speed * Time.deltatime;
```

Comment: Thank  you  for your answer to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I always just use `transform.Translate()` usually moves the object for me.